# embedly is not working properly

Tags: javascript, embedly

I am trying to embed content on my website. I looked on to options, but the best i could find is embedly. I hav gone thru there help and other stuff but i am not able to use even as they recommend. Moreover not many tutorials available for learning.. If someone could tell me where hav i gone wrong..

### HTML

```
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.embed.ly/jquery.embedly-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type= "text" id="txt-box">
     <input type="button" onclick="generate();">
     <div id="embed">
     </div>
    <a href="some you tube link">sometext</a>
    </body>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var value = document.getElementById('txt-box').value;
      document.getElementById("embed").innerHTML = '<a href="'+value+'">'+value+'</a>';
      $('#embed a').embedly({key: 'i have placed my key here'});
    </script>
```